# Get scopes from an access_token

Tags: oauth2

When i got an access_token using the OAUTH2 endpoint, is there any way to check which scopes it is valid for? E.g. call some endpoint to get a list of valid scopes.

Comment: You can get the scopes from the original response to your call to obtain the token, but I'm not sure there's a way to get them thereafter. Is that relevant to your application or are you not getting the token yourself?

Comment: @DavidReed i am building an app using Salesforce Mobile SDK, so the original response is abstracted away. Sometimes OAUTH2 SPs offer an api that lets the consumer check if the token is valid for a given scope (e.g. Google, Facebook etc.) so I was wondering if that is an option in SF also.

Answer (score 3):

You want the [token introspection endpoint](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oidc_token_introspection.htm&type=5). It's listed under the umbrella of OpenID Connect but it'll work on oAuth access tokens. You're going to need credentials *other* than your access token to authorize yourself to the introspection endpoint, e.g. client id + client secret.